# Как создать рандомную точку с двумя значениями координат?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Как создать рандомную точку с координатами с 2 значениями на промежутке (−5,5)×(−5,5) ?

Нужна рандомная точка при поиске минимума с помощью градиентного спуска. Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно использовать библиотеки, то чуть короче если взять `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

x, y = (np.random.rand(2) - 0.5) * 10
print(x, y)
# -3.2738632035969104 4.162504209779479
```

Правда, тут нижняя граница может попасть, а верхняя нет, т.е. результат будет в диапазоне `[-5,5) x [-5,5)`.

Answer (score 1):

а что мешает 2 раза сгенерировать по 1 координате в диапазоне?

```
min = -5.5
max = 5.5

x = min + (max - min) * random.random()
y = min + (max - min) * random.random()
```

P.S.

я надеюсь, что промежуток `(−5,5)×(−5,5)` - это опечатка?

А... по разъяснению автора понял, что надо взять случайную точку в заданной области на плоскости

**способ 1 (квадратная область со стороной size):**

```
x0 = -5.5
y0 = -5.5
size = 0.01

x = x0 - size / 2 + size * random.random()
y = y0 - size / 2 + size * random.random()
```

**способ 2 (круглая область с радиусом size):**

делаем через полярные координаты:

```
x0 = -5.5
y0 = -5.5
size = 0.01

r = size * random.random()
phi = 2 * 3.14159 * random.random()

x = x0 + r * math.cos(phi)
y = y0 + r * math.sin(phi)
```

Comment: ето область на плоскости, в пределах которой нужно взять рандомную точку с 2 координатами. В переделах етой же плоскости и находится минимум функции.

Comment: понял, добавил в ответ - посмотрите, это то что вы имели в виду?